# Cancel Axios post request outside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

GET requests canceling fine in this example:

```
export default function Post (props) {
  const _cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source()

  useEffect(() => {
    const _loadAsyncData = async () => {
      await axios.get('/post'), { cancelToken: _cancelToken.token })
    }

    _loadAsyncData()

    return () => {
      _cancelToken.cancel()
    }
  }, [])
  return ()
}
```

But when I need save form via POST request, my code looks like:

```
export default function Form (props) {
  const _cancelToken = axios.CancelToken.source()
  const _zz = { qq: 'QQ' }

  const handleCreate = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    _zz.qq = 'ZZ'

    await axios.post('/form'), {}, { cancelToken: _cancelToken.token })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(_zz.qq)
      _cancelToken.cancel()
    }
  }, [])

  return ()
}
```

Request not cancel and my `_zz.qq` always `'QQ'` instead `'ZZ'`. It's working fine without hooks, but I like hooks and want to use hooks for new components.

I want to cancel request when `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: What if you put `_cancelToken.cancel` in the dependencies array `useEffect(....., [_cancelToken.cancel])`?

Comment: seems as expected, you unmount component and thus awaiting on axios.post gets cancelled and your `_zz.qq = 'ZZ'` dont seem to run as such.

Comment: Teneff, it's cancel immediately after request init (but it's works), and I thinks it's right. I need cancel when component unmount not when token changing.

Comment: Rikin, I not sure that I understand you. `_zz.qq` not changed outside useEffect. I need to cancel request when component unmounting.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you're losing the changes between renders.  During the `handleCreate` call the variable changes only for that render.  When the `useEffect` is run on a subsequent render/unmounting, you're resetting `_zz` to `{ qq: 'QQ' }`.  In order to get around this you need to use references.

```
export default function Form (props) {
  const cancelToken = useRef(null)
  const zz = useRef({ qq: 'QQ' })

  const handleCreate = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    cancelToken.current = axios.CancelToken.source() 
    zz.current = { qq: 'ZZ' }

    await axios.post('/form'), {}, { cancelToken: cancelToken.current.token })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(zz.current) //this should now be {qq : 'ZZ'}
      if (cancelToken.current) {
        cancelToken.current.cancel()
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return null
}
```